# To console/check value in painless script

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-painless

Do we have any option to print/console the variables value in painless script? To get it view in the simulated result.

Answer (score -7, accepted):

It was sorted out and we can easily display the variable value using the '+variable+' operator

Comment: Can you please give an example?

Comment: Could you please explain how / what this means?